# Conditionally exclude equations from an align environment

Tags: align, conditionals

Is there a way to re-use an align-environment (via `\input`), but slightly change it due to different booleans setup before inclusion? The rationale is that I want to build up such an environment piecewise (and explain the additions) in my document without repeating my self (in order to not make a mistake when editing some equations later on).

The following does **not** work, but shows my intention: I want to use the two equations and change the appearence based on the `ifthenelse` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  & 42 & = \text{the answer}
         {\ifthenelse{true}{\\ & 23 & = \text{a mysterious number}}{}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with placing the `ifthenelse` outside of the align, both branches of which contain a complete `align` environment?

Comment: Yes, as I would have to repeat lots of code that might change in the future (hence I would probably produce inconsistencies between the branches)

Answer (score 2):

tabulars (and align is a tabular) are complicated beasts: The cells are groups and they look ahead for the next & and so quite often clash with conditionals which look ahead too. align is even more complicated as it does two passes. One strategy that often works is to use primitive ifs and to hide the `&` in a command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,ifthen}
\newif\ifshowline
\newcommand\alignline{\\& 23 & = \text{a mysterious number}} 
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  & 42 & = \text{the answer}
  %\showlinetrue
  \ifshowline
     \alignline
  \else
     % something else
  \fi
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```